Yocto project :Installing dlib with python bindings
I used layer 'meta-iris-thirdparty' to build image with dlib package .But it is getting installed as shared library(libdlib). Is there a method that can help with installing dlib with python bindings in yocto image ?
Since its installed as shared library ,I am not able to import it .
